# Texturing and Baking a really large terrain (for a game)

Tags: texture-baking, baking

so first off, this is for a 3rd person video game:

Say I have a 15 kilometer square world, which will I’ll need to texture (I’m thinking procedurally) and then bake out into image textures (our engine requires UV maps).

Baking out a single map for a 15 km square world sounds prohibitive… can anyone give me any advice on how to pull this off?

Thanks!!

Comment: This question sounds more like game development. Have you tried https://gamedev.stackexchange.com? I think it depends on the game engine you want to use. But I don't think you have to bake one huge texture, but several normal sized ones. Older games loaded only a part of the world. When the player entered a transition area the next part is loaded. The loading is often hidden by a cut scene (door opens, passing through an airlock, a train ride, a warp jump, etc). Nowadays, modern games can seamlessly stream the world data such as meshes, textures, sound, ...